# auto crop pictures that are different resolutions

Tags: crop

Anyone know a free program or method that can auto crop pictures?  The pictures I have are different dimensions.  I want them to be 100 x 100 for uploading them to the company Intranet page.  It should also auto crop the face.

I know about GIMP, but I don't think this does that.

Thanks,

Tony

Comment: I implemented http://liuliu.me/ccv/js/nss/ into some php and imagemagick code a few years ago to auto crop faces. I suppose you could run the face detect code first and if there is a face crop it and if no face just crop it.

Answer (score 0):

Imagemagick?

It includes a command-line toolset, without precise details of what you're trying to do - I can't give you the exact command.

Something around the `convert -crop <size> *.<ext>`

`convert` documentation: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php

Project documentation: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/